# jQuery UI Datepicker - default to show a month that is not the current one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

When a user opens the datepicker, I would like it to open showing a specific month, but not select any dates in that month.

The 'defaultDate' option is not what I want, it selects a date in that month.

I want the equivalent of a user opening the calendar and clicking the next month arrow a few times without selecting anything.

Basically the date my user should be selecting is usually in November so I want to show them November when the calendar opens, but not assume they want to choose November 1. They are free to change the month after it opens.

Any ideas?

Here is some sample code:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

How do I make this open the month of November when the calendar opens. The only thing I could think of doing is sending a bunch of click() events to the next button after the calendar opens. This seems messy and may look strange to the user.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your current code look like?

Comment: @Twisty, added a bit more info but I feel this is not a use case that the developers allowed for.

Comment: By default, today's date *is* "selected" (if available - its `td` has `ui-date-picker-current-day` and `a` has `ui-state-active` class, until a different date is chosen), but it is not obvious from the UI as today's date is styled differently anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you review: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

You can see that this does do what you want:

> - **Date:** A date object containing the default date.
> - **Number:** A number of days from today. For example `2` represents two days from today and `-1` represents yesterday.
> - **String:** A string in the format defined by the `dateFormat` option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are `"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, and `"d"` for days. For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents one month and seven days from today.

So for example, you could use:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1m"
  });
});
```

A day in the month has to be selected. That said, you can adjust the `dateFormat` too: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1m"
    dateFormat: mm/yy
  });
});
```

When the date is stored to the input, the text in the would be "04/2017" as an example.